# check and get parameter from url of current page asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, httpwebrequest

am trying to get the parameter "id" from the query string of the requested page like this

```
If Request.QueryString IsNot Nothing AndAlso _
            Request.QueryString.GetKey("id") IsNot Nothing Then
            DeleteVehicle(Request.QueryString.GetKey("id"))
 End If
```

but i get this error

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 

Line 16:         If Request.QueryString IsNot Nothing AndAlso _
Line 17:             Request.QueryString.GetKey("id") IsNot Nothing Then

Source File: G:\projects_backup\Toaab\Toaa\admin\vehicle\view.aspx.vb    Line: 16
```

please can you help me

EDIT

Am calling this in the page_load event

the same page (which has autogenerated link) is called through a hyperlink

i also change the code to

```
If Request.QueryString("id") IsNot Nothing OrElse Request.QueryString("id") IsNot String.Empty Then
 DeleteVehicle(Request.QueryString("id").ToString)
End If
```

Comment: What happens when you use `Request.QueryString("id")`?

Comment: Where (in what method, stage of page life cycle, etc.) are you executing this code?

Comment: I don't know VB.NET so well but `AndAlso` looks to me like it will evaluate the statement on the left AND the statement on the right, even if the statement on the left is false. So doing GetKey on the Nothing object `Request.QueryString` would throw this error.

Comment: i change the code, but still get the error, if the query string is there or empty

Comment: `AndAlso` **ensures** short circuiting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To see if a value exists in the QueryString, check to see whether the value equates to an empty string rather than null:

Try this instead:

```
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString("id")) = False Then
    DeleteVehicle(Request.QueryString("id"))
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

1. There is no Overload in `C#/VB.Net` which provides String Parameter in `GetKey` function.
2. If you check all event of  `Page Life Cycle`, `Request.QueryString` value never comes null(Besides, it contains some not null value).
3. Try Changing your code like below.

---

```
If Request.QueryString("id") IsNot Nothing 
                 AndAlso String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString("id")) = False Then
    DeleteVehicle(Request.QueryString("id").ToString)
End If
```

Comment: You really should use `AndAlso` instead of `And`. `AndAlso` will jump out if the first condition is false. `And` will execute both conditions every time. I've found `And` only useful nowadays when you are comparing return values from functions.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the Params collection.  It will be good for Querystring as well as Form based params.  You can make an easy test for 'id' like this.

```
Request.Params.AllKeys.Contains("id")
```